# Git Flow GitHub pull request isn't working as expected

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I've been using github for a while now where I create feature branches (locally) add commits and then push.  Once pushed I perform a pull request with a "develop" branch, once happy, merge the feature branch into the develop branch. This seems pretty much standard practice. I use git flow and this is my standard practice for creating and pushing a feature branch

```
git flow feature start test
git add . 
git commit -am 'test commit'
git push -u origin feature/test
```

I then would create a pull request on GH, once merged I run:

```
git flow feature finish test
```

Which merges the feature branch back into my develop.  Then from my local develop branch:

```
git pull
```

And I start the whole process again

For some reason now, when I go to create a PR in Github I get the following:

[image: Pull request message]

What exactly does this mean?  I can perform **git diff** between the two branches and I can see my changes locally, also a visual inspection of the two branches on Github shows my changes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git flow feature finish test` command will:

1. Merge the `feature` branch `test` back into `develop`
2. Delete the `feature` branch
3. Check out `develop`

So once you have run the `feature finish` command, the `test` branch should no longer exist. This would explain why GitHub is throwing it's hands up ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Even if GitHub can still find the `feature` branch, it should be identical to the `develop` branch at this point which would likely trip GitHub up also.

Source: [git-flow cheatsheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 1):

I've got around this by doing this:

```
git flow feature finish test -k //this will keep the feature branch
```

Then after merge happens, you should still see the PR still there marker as "merged" instead of "closed". Finally, you can delete the remote feature branch

```
git flow feature delete test -r
```